# Обработка исключений C#

Tags: c#, исключения

Решил написать калькулятор на C#, нужно форматировать строку в TextBox в int, при этом обработать исключение при вводе алфавита.Но при этом всё равно выводится ошибка, извиняюсь если глупый вопрос, гуглил, ответа не нашел

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int NamberA = int.Parse (textBox1.Text);
            try
            {
                NamberA = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            }
            catch(FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Вы ввели буквы, будьте впредь аккуратны");
            }
        }
```

[image: Эта ошибка]

Comment: первый вызов int NamberA = int.Parse (textBox1.Text); у Вас вне try {} catch; Поставьте там просто объявление  int NamberA; а это NamberA = int.Parse (textBox1.Text) воткните в try {} catch;

Comment: `MessageBox` моментально задолбает не очень аккуратного пользователя. Не используйте его для сигнализации о таких ошибках. Используйте [ErrorProvider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider?view=netframework-4.8). А ещё лучше, возьмите [NumericUpDown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown?view=netframework-4.8) для ввода чисел.

Comment: используйте `int.TryParse()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка в том, что у вас метод `int.Parse` находится вне блока `try/catch`. Чтобы правильно обработать исключение, нужно метод, выбрасывающий исключение, поместить в `try`-часть. У вас почему-то два раза осуществляется преобразование строки в число двумя разными способами. Поэтому один из них нужно убрать. Пусть останется `int.Parse`:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int NamberA;
    try
    {
        NamberA = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    }
    catch(FormatException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Вы ввели буквы, будьте впредь аккуратны");
    }
}
```

**P.S.** Вообще, для калькулятора я бы поступил немного по-другому. Вместо события `TextChanged` я бы обрабатывал событие `KeyPress`. И сделал бы такой обработчик для `textBox`:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar);
}
```

В этом случае в textBox вообще нельзя ввести ничего, кроме цифр.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае, также можно воспользоваться методом TryParse()

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int NumberA;
            if(!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out NumberA))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Вы ввели буквы, будьте впредь аккуратны");
            }   
        }
```

TryParse возвращает true, если получилось преобразовать строку в число и кладёт в NumberA это число и возвращает false, если преобразование не произошло.

Comment: Думаю всё же не стоит избежать try catch. На вашм случие если вводит 11111111111 то TryParse не работает, потому что это уже не int. А ваше сообщение говорит что он вводил буквы

Comment: @DIlshod ведь не важно, что написать в выходном сообщении. Можно указать: "Введены некорректные данные", или вообще сделать проверку на вводимые символы методом IsDigit() и делать return, когда вводится не число.
При этом, в том коде, который указал автор, тоже если ввести 11111111111 , вылезет сообщение про буквы.
Я просто скопировал эту ошибку для примера

Comment: Не надо "избежать" try catch. Хорошая вещь в try / catch (или стилях, полученных из него) состоит в том, что каждая функция (или метод / процедура / и т. Д.) Будет иметь один общий блок для «нормальной» обработки и другой блок для обработки исключений. Этот подход гораздо проще поддерживать и тестировать, чем подход с большим количеством if, если он присутствует при каждом вызове функции, особенно если код «раскручивается» из состояния ошибки.

Comment: @DIlshod я с вами согласен, слово избежать подобрано некорректно. Если бы автор указал ещё какие-то проверки, то мой ответ уже был бы не так уместен и предполагал использование if'ов