# Закрытие формы после исключения

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать чтобы после выпада исключения форма не закрывалась.
На примере, у меня есть форма с текстбоксами, если они заполнены то данные успешно передаются в датагрид, а если поля не заполнены вылетает MessageBox с подписью, после исключение и форма закрывается. Хотелось бы чтобы форма после MessageBoxa работала дальше для ввода полей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ловите исключение через `try-catch`

Comment: можно пожалуйста поподробней, не сталкивался еще

Comment: [вот этот вопрос посмотрите этот случай похож на ваш](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/971566/319552), отличается только само исключение

Comment: а еще вы можете посмотреть на какой строчке у вас вылезает исключение, найти там ошибку и исправить, у вас наверно написано `a.b` и в `a` как-то null попал

Comment: разобрался, через отладчик посмотрел где вылазит исключение и этот блок поместил в try catch, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(textBox1.Text!="" .... textBox<N>.Text!=""){

//Твой код, соответственно выполняющий запрос в Datagrid.

    MessageBox.Show("Данные Успешно сохранены","Успешно!");
    this.Close(); //закрываем после успешного сохранения
}
else {
    MessageBox.Show("Необходимо заполнить все поля!","Ошибка!");
}
```

Comment: Ответ ни о чем.